# Problems with movement GameMaker studio 2

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I am make a game for school, within this game I have an (hero)asset, this asset walks on keypresses and stops when I don't press the key.

The only problem I have, is when the I stop walking de animation keeps on running. In other words, it stands still, but it still walks.

This is my code:

```
/////////////////////
//     MOVING      //
/////////////////////

if(keyboard_check(vk_left)){                // moving left collisions
    dir=-1;                                 // set the correct direction
    image_xscale = dir;                     // make the sprite face the correct direction
                    // if we are not jumping or falling


    sprite_index = spr_denpman_Loop;                // set the sprite to walking


    x=x-xspeed                              // move the player left
    c2 = -1;
    c3 = -1;
    // check the points at the bottom of the sprite
    c1 = tilemap_get_at_pixel(obj_Spel.map,x-(sprite_get_width(sprite_index)/2),y-1);               // left
    c3 = tilemap_get_at_pixel(obj_Spel.map,x,y-1);                                                  // center
    if( y&$3f>0 ) c2=tilemap_get_at_pixel(obj_Spel.map,x-(sprite_get_width(sprite_index)/2),y+1);   // left below (only check if there is a tile below)
    if(c1 == 3) || (c2 == 3){                                                                   // if we are intersecting with a box
        x = real(x&$ffffffc0)+(sprite_get_width(sprite_index)/2);                               // stop the player from moving
    }

    if(x < 0){                              // the the player has moved off the edge of the screen
        x = room_width;                     // wrap around to the other side of the screen
    }
}else if(keyboard_check(vk_right)){         // moving right collisions (check with else so that both directions cant be triggered at the same time)
    dir=1;                                  // set the correct direction
    image_xscale = dir;                     // make the sprte face the correct direction 
                    // if we are not jumping or falling
    sprite_index = spr_denpman_Loop;                // set the sprite to walking
    image_speed = anim_speed;   
    x=x+xspeed;                             // move the player right
    c2 = -1;
    c3 = -1;
    // check the points at the bottom of the sprite
    c1 = tilemap_get_at_pixel(obj_Spel.map,x+(sprite_get_width(sprite_index)/2),y-1);               // right
    c3 = tilemap_get_at_pixel(obj_Spel.map,x,y-1);                                                  // center
    if( y&$3f>0 ) c2=tilemap_get_at_pixel(obj_Spel.map,x+(sprite_get_width(sprite_index)/2),y+1);   // right below (only check if there is a tile below)
    if(c1 == 3) || (c2 == 3){                                                                   // if we are intersecting with a box
            x = real(x&$ffffffc0)+obj_Spel.tilesize-(sprite_get_width(sprite_index)/2);         // stop the player from moving
    }

    if(x > room_width){                     // the the player has moved off the edge of the screen
        x = 0;                              // wrap around to the other side of the screen
    }

}
```

Comment: This function tries to do too many things on a too low level. Split it up into meaningful blocks and analyze part by part.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, the sprite will remain at the walking sprite because that's the last sprite you've given a command to changes into. 
You also need to make a command to show the standing sprite for when it stops walking.

Place this at the end of your if-else-statement:

```
else 
{
    sprite_index = spr_denpman_Loop;  //stops the player if there's no key pressed.
}
```

(And replace the `spr_denpman_Loop` with the name of your standing sprite)

And on a sidenote, please look at your own code and understand what you're reading as well. I know the demo you're using, and that only explains the very basics of the program, I can't recommend using that as a base for a game. Since a lot of code can be simplified.